# How to allow extra fields with bolt compiler?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

When defining a type, it disallows any extra fields. Is there a way to allow extra fields in the bolt language?

Specifically how to avoid in output:

```
  "$other": {
    ".validate": "false"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Bolt only validates schema if the type is applied

```
type Person {
  name: String;
}

path /person is Person;
path /personNoValidation; // not validated
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I'm aware it prevents extra fields. My question is i *want* to *allow* extra fields. How do i do that?

Comment: @AJcodez Oh man. How did I miss that? Sorry need moar coffee and will answer shortly.

Comment: So there's no way without creating a new data path. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: You can also use optional types, but that's only for what you specify.

Comment: Yeah, i wanted to enforce certain user fields, and then allow whatever else is returned with auth sign in. I've just added *every field* by hand with optional null tho, and it's the same thing and better inline docs. So i'm happy, even if my fingers hurt.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. You need to manually delete the $other: rule to allow optional fields. Adding 
`$optional: Any | Null;` 
won't work because Firebase won't allow two wildcard properties.